# Email section refreshes when Case record is updated/saved

Tags: email, chatter

If an agent is typing an Email (under Chatter component) and edits a field on the Case record, hits Save, then the written Email disappears (as all components on the page are refreshed).

This might be standard SF behaviour but wanted to confirm - Is there a way in which the Email section is **not** refreshed whenever a Case record is saved? It's inconvenient for users to have to write emails separately in Notes and then copy them over to workaround this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable email draft functionality from the Setup Menu> Support settings> Enable the checkbox "Enable Email Drafts".
[image: clickpath to enable the setting]

This will not discard the email text when you edit and save a field on case object.

On an additional note,you can also save Your Chatter Posts as Drafts as mentioned in the Winter'19 [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_chatter_draft_posts.htm) .Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Swetha for both the settings - useful information!